# Why do the 2 LINQ queries get evaluated differently

Tags: c#, linq

Query 1

```
       var resulty = db.QIS
            .Where(w=>w.QSA.Any(a => a.QSID != w.QSID))
            .Select(s => s.QSID).ToList();
```

Query 2

```
        var resultz = db.QIS
            .Where(w=>w.QSA.Where(h => h.QSID == w.QSID).Select(s => s.QSID).FirstOrDefault() != w.QSID)
            .Select(s => s.QSID).ToList();
```

Table `QIS` and `QSA` are related `Many:Many`. The idea here is to find how many `QIS.ID's` are not Found in `QSA` where `QIS.QID == QSA.QID`.

`Query 1` returns `0`

`Query 2` on the other hand gives me what I expected to see ( the list off all non matching QIS records.)

Why will the any not work? - i found myself running into the same situation a couple of times now in seperate scenarios... thanks for any help / thoughts.

PS: Prefer method syntax.

Comment: `Any()` returns a boolean, not an `IEnumerable`. In any case, neither query makes much sense.  What's happening between `db.QIS` and `w.QSA`?  Seems like there's a dot missing there somewhere.  Also, your first query has one too many close parentheses.  Why don't you copy/paste your actual working code here?

Comment: Sorry about that, i tried to get all the quirks out before posting, take another look, also when I flip the != into == ( at the .Any comparison) i get the opposite values of what i want. logically i thought i can just place a != to get what i needed.

Comment: You're double `where` on the second query is confusing me. What's that doing? Also, this seems like it'd be a super-trivial problem using `inner join` when writing SQL yourself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the filtering in your second version, will only be true if the inner `Where` clause returns no elements, so that `FirstOrDefault()` returns `null` or `0` (depending on if the type is nullable or not).

```
w=>w.QSA.Where(h => h.QSID == w.QSID)
.Select(s => s.QSID).FirstOrDefault() != w.QSID
```

Which is equivalent to (now assuming `QSID` is a non nullable numeric type, if it is nullable, use `null` instead of zero):

```
w=>w.QSA.Where(h => h.QSID == w.QSID)
.Select(s => s.QSID).FirstOrDefault() == 0
```

which can be rewritten to:

```
w=>w.QSA.Where(h => h.QSID == w.QSID).FirstOrDefault() == null
```

which can be rewritten to:

```
w=>!w.QSA.Any(h => h.QSID == w.QSID)
```

which is nearly the same as your initial version, but not exactly. You still want to check for equivalence *inside* the `Any()` filter, but then negate the result.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and answering the question, never thought to negate the Any() filter at the beginning. Thanks!